# Maximum number of point you can get by putting N coins at 4x4 grid

Tags: number-theory

The Problem:
Given $4 \times 4$ grid and $N$ coins, what is the maximum point you can get? If a row/column/diagonal (every diagonal with $\geq 2$ cells not diagonals with only $1$ cell) have even number of coins inside it ($0$ is even), you will get one point. For example, if $N = 4$ and you put those $4$ coins in the center cells, you will get $14$ points.

What should I do to solve this problem? I tried to use modulo like this:

The Grid:
$$ \begin{matrix} a & b & c & d \\ e & f & g & h \\ i & j & k & l \\ m & n & o & p \\ \end{matrix} $$

Row 1: $$ (a+b+c+d+1) \mod 2 $$
Row 2: $$ (e+f+g+h+1) \mod 2 $$
etc.

so
$$\text{points} = (a+b+c+d+1) \mod 2 + (e+f+g+h) \mod 2 + ... $$

but you can't just merge a variable from a group (like row1, row2, etc) with same variable from other groups because of the modulo, right?

Comment: Please use MathJax when writing mathematics. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: okay, updated it

Comment: But please be consistent and use it everywhere.